# What is the role of websocket in webRTC?

Tags: html, websocket, webrtc

I built the server into Java,The server sends (image)data to the web browser through a web socket.So far it works fine.
and I wand that The web browser  send data from the server to another web browser (client) using webRTC, So I looked for the webrtc... 
I noticed that there are occasions when you need to use webSocket with webRTC
What is the role of websocket in webRTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *establish* a WebRTC connection between two browsers, these browsers will have to negotiate a connection first. To negotiate a connection they need to be able to talk to each other. But they cannot talk to each other because they have not established a connection yet.

That's where a *signalling server* comes in. That's a server that both peers are already connected to and which can relay messages between them until they have established a connection. Using a websocket connection for this purpose is the most useful way, since it's a (soft) realtime bi-direction communication channel, exactly what you want when relaying messages as quickly as possible.

It doesn't *have* to be a websocket though; AJAX and/or long-polling will do too, but they have more overhead and are slower, which means it will take longer to negotiate the WebRTC connection.

Comment: thank you!! more question..! If two clients connect to localhost: 8080,
What are you sending and receiving from the server via websocket ??What is the message that the server received through websocket and what should the server do with it?